# Wildfly 8.2 fails to load jbossws-cxf-client module

Tags: jboss, cxf, wildfly

I am working on a web application that contains a Soap client and that needs to have access to the cxf Client implmentation, because we have to use different certificates for different calls to the remote endpoint.

Wildfly comes with a module jbossws-cxf-client which has dependencies to all the different cxf modules required. There is a maven version of this module as well.

In the maven module pom file we have a dependency like so:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.ws.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>jbossws-cxf-client</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Note that the version has been matched with the version that is mentioned in the wildfly 8.2 release notes:http://wildfly.org/news/2014/11/20/WildFly82-Final-Released/

When deploying our application we get the following message from the log:

```
14:22:12,492 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (weld-worker-1) WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from nl.topicuszorg.lsp.service.MultipleCertificatePingStubServiceImpl because of underlying class loading error: Type org.apache.cxf.transport.Conduit from [Module "deployment.kdplus-lsphub-server-1.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader] not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.
14:22:12,689 INFO  [org.apache.deltaspike.core.util.ProjectStageProducer] (MSC service thread 1-2) Computed the following DeltaSpike ProjectStage: Production
14:22:13,628 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."kdplus-lsphub-server-1.1-SNAPSHOT.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."kdplus-lsphub-server-1.1-SNAPSHOT.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type PingStubService with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject nl.topicuszorg.lsp.service.PingPongServiceImpl.pingStubService
  at nl.topicuszorg.lsp.service.PingPongServiceImpl.pingStubService(PingPongServiceImpl.java:0)
```

The real problem is logged as INFO, strangely enough. org.apache.cxf.transport.Conduit can not be loaded. This is part of the org.apache.cxf module, and should be loaded transitively by loading the jbossws-cxf-client module.

It should not be necessary, but we also implicitely declare the module dependencies in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <excludes>
        </excludes>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.slf4j"/>
            <module name="org.apache.cxf"/>
            <module name="jbossws-cxf-client"/>
            <module name="org.apache.cxf.impl"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

It seems the module is not loaded, I don't know why. I can not find a way to check which modules have been loaded.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out I had to move my jboss-deployment-structure.xml from the META-INF to the WEB-INF directory.
Bummer...